# Subscript out of range error when changing cell color

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, subscript

Hi i'm new to vba and i might not really undestand much of it, but i can't explain why i get a "Runtime error 9: Subscript out of range" error, when the code should change the background color of the cell to another

```
 Sub CompareWorksheets(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet)
    Dim r As Long, c As Integer
    Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, lc1 As Integer, lc2 As Integer
    Dim maxR As Long, maxC As Integer, cf1 As String, cf2 As String
    Dim DiffCount As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws1.UsedRange
        lr1 = .Rows.Count
        lc1 = .Columns.Count
    End With
    With ws2.UsedRange
        lr2 = .Rows.Count
        lc2 = .Columns.Count
    End With
    maxR = lr1
    maxC = lc1
    If maxR < lr2 Then maxR = lr2
    If maxC < lc2 Then maxC = lc2
    DiffCount = 0
    For c = 1 To maxC
        For r = 1 To maxR
            cf1 = ""
            cf2 = ""
            On Error Resume Next
            cf1 = ws1.Cells(r, c).FormulaLocal
            cf2 = ws2.Cells(r, c).FormulaLocal
            On Error GoTo 0
            If cf1 <> cf2 Then
                DiffCount = DiffCount + 1
                ws1.Cells(r, c).Activate
                ws1.Cells(r, c).Select
 =============> ws1.Cells(r, c).Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(200, 20, 20) <============
                End If
            Next r
        Next c
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Cell.Interior.ColorIndex` is not a **RGB** value, but an enum value.
Possible values are:

- `xlColorIndexAutomatic`  which means Automatic color
- `xlColorIndexNone`   which means No color

This is the reason for why you can't successfully set it to a **RGB** value.

To set the background color to a **RGB** color, use the `Interior.Color` property instead.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered using **Interior.Color** with **&H** tag within RGB(#,#,#) works as well.

**Example:**

> RGB = 192 0 0  ------- Hex = #C00000  ------ RGB(&HC0, &H0, &H0)
>
> RGB = 84 130 53 ---- Hex = #548235 ------ RGB(&H54, &H82, &H35)

> Range("C1").Interior.Color = RGB(&HC0, &H0, &H0)
>
> Range("C1").Interior.Color = RGB(&H54, &H82, &H35)

> Cells(1, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(&HC0, &H0, &H0)
>
> Cells(1, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(&H54, &H82, &H35)